# Add column to invoice2

Tags: invoice

I have an invoice like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{invoice2}

\begin{document}
\begin{invoice}
\invoiceitem{5}{Googling}{23}
\invoiceitem{1}{Reclining}{23}
\end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

to which I would like to add a date column. Is this possible with the `invoice2` package? Is there another package which is more customizable in terms of columns and provides summing of the items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could a workaround like this be acceptable?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{invoice2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c@{}c}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \toprule
            \textbf{\scriptsize Date}\\
            \midrule
            25.09.2017\\
            26.09.2017\\
            \midrule
            \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular} &
        \parbox{210pt}{%
            \begin{invoice}
                \invoiceitem{5}{Googling}{23}
                \invoiceitem{1}{Reclining}{23}
            \end{invoice}
        }
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Benjamin You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer!